# How to start orage in the background?

Tags: xfce, calendar

I added orage to the startup applications in XFce, but when I open the desktop, the orage calendar appears in the middle of the screen. I just need orage to start and appear in the notification error, so that it can display the alerts.

How can I start orage in the background in XFce without showing the calendar window?

Answer (score 1):

My experience with things like that popping up when XFCE starts has been that it's due to XFCE's loading of a saved session in which the things had been opened and are consequently being reopened at startup.

To get around this took what might seem like a bit of voodoo...

1. Log in to start XFCE,
2. Set up everything the way you want it at startup (presumably with orage, other panel items, and everything else closed),
3. Pull up the logout dialog,
4. Check the "Save session for future logins" box if it's not checked already, and
5. Logout of XFCE.

Then...

1. Log in to again start XFCE,
2. Make sure everything's the way you intended,
3. Pull up the logout dialog.
4. If the "Save session for future logins" box is unchecked, you should be good.
5. If the "Save session for future logins" box ***is checked***, then uncheck it, logout, and then log back in again. All should still come up the way you intended and you should find the "Save session for future logins" box unchecked when examining the logout dialog.

Comment: This did not work. Orage did not load at all when I logged back in after saving the session with Orage open in the notification area only.

Comment: Ah... Adding an item to your "Application Autostart" list in "Session and Startup" that runs `orage` should start it at login without it being dependent on a saved session. Then, in the preferences of the calendar itself, set "Calendar start" to `Hide`.